# How to sort an array of object by a specific field Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, sorting, web

I have an array containing multiple objects with multiple fields, and I'm trying to sort the array in decending order from the largest "Views" value to the lowest. but when I run my code it outputs a few in order, but the majority are random. There are a lot more array rows in my project if that could be affecting it.

```
list = [{title: "Test1", views: "25"}, {title: "Test2", "105"}, {title: "Test3", views: "12"}]
var len = list.length - 1;
list.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.views.localeCompare(b.views) || b.views - a.views;
});
for(var x = 0; x < len; x++) {
    displayFunc(list[x].title, list[x].views);
}
```

Desired output:

```
{title: "Test2", views: "105"}, {title: "Test1", "25"}, {title: "Test3", views: "12"}
```

Comment: Why `.localeCompare()` for numbers?

Comment: localeCompare is sorting them in alphabetic order, your `||` option is only triggered when the values are the same, and subtracting them will only yield 0 again. Just use the subtraction `list.sort((a, b) => b.views - a.views);`

Comment: @pilchard Ahhh, thank you so much! I originally tried using 'list.sort()' but I didn't set it up properly so ended up switching to '.localeCompare()' hoping that would work. Thank you very much, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you dont need a localecompare here:

```js
const list = [{title: "Test1", views: "25"}, {title: "Test2", views: "105"}, {title: "Test3", views: "12"}]

console.log(list.sort((a,b)=>{
    return  b.views - a.views
}));
```

Comment: When your anonymous method implementation is a single statement you can omit the `return` and curly brackets.   This can be more simply written as `console.log(list.sort((a,b)=>b.views - a.views))`

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your code. I corrected your version and give you a somewhat better, more modern version.

```js
const list = [{title: "Test1", views: "25"}, {title: "Test2", views: "105"}, {title: "Test3", views: "12"}];
var len = list.length;
const list_sorted = list.sort(function (a, b) {
    return parseInt(b.views, 10) - parseInt(a.views, 10);
});
for(var x = 0; x < len; x++) {
    console.log(list[x].title, list[x].views);
}

/// Better
list
  .map(el => ({ ...el, views: parseInt(el.views, 10) }))
  .sort((a,b) => b.views - a.views)
  .forEach(el => console.log(el.title, el.views));
```

Comment: Always specify a radix when using [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#parameters), it does not default to 10.

Comment: Good one. Therefore linting is good,

Comment: @pilchard _"...it does not default to 10"_ - It does -> [19.2.5 `parseInt ( string, radix )`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/global-object.html#sec-parseint-string-radix) -> Step 9

Comment: @Andreas it's not a hard default but a fallback after parsing the input. If it always defaulted to 10 `parseInt('0x10')` and `parseInt('0x10', 10)` would return the same value

Comment: @pilchard _"but a fallback after parsing the input"_ - How would that even make any sense? I first parse the input and then later in the execution I determine the value of the radix parameter? o.O Your example is a special case that is handled in step 10.

Comment: Fair enough, so it sets it to 10 and then parses the input to set it to 16 in the next step. Either way 10 is not the default (as it is defaulting to 16 in this case)

Comment: 10 is the default, but `0x` is just a special case that will overwrite a missing radix (and the default `10`)...

Answer (score 0):

We can use any key available in object to sort. As per your requirement, 'view' is used here,

```
const list = [{title: "Test1", views: "25"}, {title: "Test2", views: "105"}, {title: "Test3", views: "12"}]

console.log(list.sort((a, b) => b.views - a.views));
```